# Unable to change time-zone properly, the time is still from the previous time-zone

Tags: arch-linux, time, timezone

I've changed my time-zone to be 1 hours behind. I've called

```
timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Bangkok
```

Although the timezone is changed, the time is still the same as in my old time-zone, that is, this time is wrong, it's 1 hours ahead of the real time:

```
$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Fri 2016-07-22 12:28:30 ICT
  Universal time: Fri 2016-07-22 05:28:30 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2016-07-22 05:28:29
       Time zone: Asia/Bangkok (ICT, +0700)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Even after reboot.

Comment: It all looks good, you asked for Bangkok time and got it. It says that Bangkok is UTC+7, this is also what I read on the web. So check that your clock is set correctly. Are you confusing UTC/GMT with London (UK) time? UK is presently one hour ahead of GMT, because of daylight wast of time.

Comment: I would recommend turning on `ntp`.

Comment: You should have a look here;) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110522/timezone-setting-in-linux

Comment: @richard, no, it's +8

Comment: Why do you think that bangkok is +8? Every where I look on the internet has bangkok at +7. They say it is `23:16` there now. In is `17:16` here in UK (London), `16:16` UTC.

Comment: @richard, I don't. I'm saying that on my computer the time is +8, although the time-zone is Bangkok. Have you read my question at all?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Can you show the output of `date; timedatectl status`

Answer (score 2):

One way to determine the local time zone is to run the following script:

```
tzselect
```

After answering a few questions about the location, the script will output the name of the time zone (e.g., Asia/Bangkok).

Then create the `/etc/localtime` file by running:

```
sudo ln -sT /usr/share/zoneinfo/<xyz> /etc/localtime
```

Replace  with the name of the time zone selected (e.g., Asia/Bangkok). In your specific case:

```
sudo ln -sT /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Bangkok /etc/localtime
```

It will change the timezone in your system wide (I mean for all users).

You can check that the new timezone is properly set automatically by running the command `date`.  For instance, I tested it right now and it returns

```
Sun Jul 24 13:26:51 ITC 2016
```

Also,  as suggested from the `tzselect` script output, you can make this change permanent for your user only by setting and exporting the TZ environment variable. To do that, you have to append the line `TZ='Asia/Bangkok'; export TZ` to the end of the `.profile` file in your home directory. You can run the command below to do that:

```
echo "TZ='Asia/Bangkok'; export TZ" >> $HOME/.profile
```

After that, you will need to log out of your current session and log back in for changes to take effect.

Comment: Better to use a symlink, than to copy.

Comment: You are right @richard. I updated the commands. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Better to always specify `-T` or `-t` option with `ln`, `cp`, `mv` as the simple `TARGET LINK_NAME` (1st form in man), and `TARGET... DIRECTORY` (3rd form in man) look the same, and depend only on if the 2nd argument is a directory.